# nftables rate limiting per multiple seconds

Tags: nftables

I'm trying to convert some iptables rules to nftables
I want to make a rule that blocks a connection if there are more than 4 attempts in a 30 seconds time span

My original iptables rules are:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
```

How can I do the same (or equivelent) in nftables?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand the iptables *recent* module does not have an equivalent in nftables, however, you should be able to achieve similar functionality using meters.

```
nft add rule ip filter INPUT tcp dport 22 ct state new meter SSHban { ip saddr and 255.255.255.255 limit rate over 8/minute burst 4 packets } counter drop
```

Documented here: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Meters

Answer (score 1):

I try months, can not find an exact match. But the I have a workaround.

```
sshPort=2222
nft add table ip sshGuard
nft add chain ip sshGuard input { type filter hook input priority 0 \; }
nft add set ip sshGuard denylist { type ipv4_addr \; flags dynamic, timeout \; timeout 5m \; }
nft add set ip sshGuard sshlist { type ipv4_addr \; flags dynamic, timeout \; timeout 5m \; }
nft add rule ip sshGuard input ct state established,related accept
nft add rule ip sshGuard input tcp dport $sshPort ct state new ip saddr @denylist reject
nft add rule ip sshGuard input tcp dport $sshPort ct state new ip saddr @sshlist add @denylist { ip saddr } accept
nft add rule ip sshGuard input tcp dport $sshPort ct state new limit rate over 2/minute burst 3 packets add @sshlist { ip saddr } counter accept
nft list table ip sshGuard
```

For a fresh state, around 5 connections will be accepted for any new IP. If the `limit rate` is hit, a new IP (not in `sshlist`) has 2 chances. For any IP in `sshlist`, only one chance left. And for any IP in `denylist`, any new connection will be rejected, until it is deleted from the `denylist` by its 5 minute timeout.